# How to install SemanticBreadcrumbLinks without composer?

Tags: mediawiki

I have restricted shell access to a site that does not have composer.

How can I install https://github.com/SemanticMediaWiki/SemanticBreadcrumbLinks/ ?

(The readme says use composer).

Comment: Copy the files to your local machine, run composer, copy them back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The only way will be to install SMW and SBL together with other semantic extension on a local machine, e.g. a laptop and move the the thus generated files over to the webspace.